# How to hover over an SVG rect?

Tags: css, svg, hover

In this piece of SVG (tried in FF 8, Safari 5.1.2, Chrome 16, all on Mac), when moving mouse over the bar, none of the browsers properly detect each on-mouse-over/out event, sometimes it works sometimes it doesnt. But it's consistent across all the browsers so it's probably something about the SVG code. Using `onmouseover` and `onmouseout` gives the same result - doesn't work properly.

What would be the correct way of implementing on hover for SVG `rect`angles?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"  width="800" height="600" version="1.1" style="display:inline">

<style type="text/css">
.bar {
    fill: none;
}
.bar:hover { 
    fill: red;
}
</style>
  <g>
   <rect class="bar" x="220" y="80" width="20" height="180" stroke="black" stroke-width="1" />
  </g>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 68, accepted):

What's happening is that the mouse events are not detected because the fill is 'none', just add:

```
.bar {
    fill: none;
    pointer-events: all;
}
```

Then it works just fine.

Answer (score 6):

`fill: none; pointer-event: all;` should work in most modern browsers, but IE9 and IE10 doesn't support `pointer-events`. Besides, you can also set `pointer-events: fill`, This `fill` value is [SVG only](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events), meaning the value of `fill` or `visibility` doesn't affect pointer events processing.

A workaround for IE9 and IE10 is to set CSS to `fill: transparent` if `pointer-events` is not supported (you can use Modernizr to detect browser features).

```js
$("#rect").mouseenter(function() {
  $(this).css("fill", "teal")
}).mouseout(function(){
  $(this).css("fill","transparent")
})
```

```css
#rect {
  fill: transparent;
  stroke: blue;
  stroke-width: 1px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<svg width=300 height=300>
  <rect id="rect" x=0 y=0 width=100 height=100></rect>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 4):

```
.bar:hover { 
    fill: red !important;
}
```

Comment: Honestly, I don’t think this would change anything. `.bar:hover` is more specific than `.bar` – so the styles take over anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Try giving it a non-transparent fill.

---

<strike>Also, the `<style>` needs to go outside the `<svg>`.</strike>

Comment: Your answer is correct, but <style> is fine within <svg>: http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/styling.html#StyleElement

Answer (score -3):

Try do it through jQuery :

```
$(".bar").attr("disable","True");
$(".bar").css("background-color","Red");

$(".bar").mouseenter(function() {   
    $(this).attr("disable","False");  
}); 

$(".bar").mouseleave(function() {   
    $(this).attr("disable","True");  
});
```

Or alternatively :

```
$(".bar").hide();
$(".bar").css("background-color","Red");

$(".bar").mouseenter(function() {   
    $(this).show();  
}); 

$(".bar").mouseleave(function() {   
    $(this).hide(); 
});
```