# Draw external svg path with jQuery SVG

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, svg, jquery-svg

I am using [jQuery SVG](http://keith-wood.name/svg.html) to draw some shapes. I now want draw an external vector image (svg format) onto my shapes. In the past I used the plugins .image() method to draw external icons, but I now want to be able to scale the icons, especially for retina displays.

I draw the icons like so:

```
this.canvas.image(($parent), icon_box.x, icon_box.y , icon_box.width, icon_box.height, 'resources/img/ui/someicon.svg');
```

That actually works, but I'd like to control the color of the svg icon/image/path from inside my jQuery Code. The jQuery SVG [image()](http://keith-wood.name/svgRef.html#image) method provides a settings parameter, but I don't know what option (if there is one) controls the color, as you can't change the color of e.g a jpg image.

So is there a way to do that? I'd also like to change the color on a mouseover event. Would you recommend not to use the [image()](http://keith-wood.name/svgRef.html#image) method? I just need to fit the icon to the icon box, as the box (and so the icon inside) scales with the rest of my shapes.

Thanks alot! Nick =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the CSS :hover pseudo classes in SVG.  You just need to define the CSS styles inside the SVG - or reference the CSS file from within the SVG.

See this question for an example: [How to hover over an SVG rect?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9208244/how-to-hover-over-an-svg-rect)

If, for some reason, you can't edit the original SVG files, you could add a style element dynamically after loading.  You could also do it by adding pointer events (onmouseover/onmouseout).

Comment: Thanks for your reply! my problem is not how to do the hover effect itself, but how to change the color of the svg image. (the fill of the paths)

Comment: The question I linked to has an example of how to do that.  As long as you are familiar with CSS it should be fairly straightforward.  Add the CSS rules to a `<style>` section in 'someicon.svg'.